# Python : Iterate over dictionaries to read arguments

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary `weeks` that is populated using a for loop. The  dictionary contains arguments passed to a function. I'd like to update the code to read second argument and pass that to the function.

```
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

weeks = {}

def generate(date):

    # generate 8 rows with 4 cells each
    for d in range(1, 32, 4):

        start = (date + timedelta(days=d)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

        week = pd.date_range(start, periods=4).to_pydatetime().tolist()

        weeks[d] = week
        
    print(weeks)

    def create(arg1):

        # do something

        return ...
```

This function populates a `dictionary` with dates as a list of values.

```
{1: [datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 13, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 14, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 15, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 16, 0, 0)], 5: [datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 17, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 18, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 19, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 20, 0, 0)],.......
```

Now I'd like to either modify the `weeks` dictionary or create a new dictionary that I'll iterate over to read the second argument of the function.

The function call:

```
[create(i)] for i in weeks[1]
```

I'd like to modify this call to include a second argument which is read from the dictionary with same structure as well. Pseudocode below:

```
[create(i,j)] for i,j in weeks[1], value[1]
```

where `value` is the new dictionary with populate, if we don't modify the existing `dict` `weeks`. I'd appreciate advise on which approach makes sense and how can I modify the function call to pass two arguments.

`value` dict will look like this:

```
value = {1: [1000, 1200, 1400, 1600], 5: [2000, 2200, 2400, 2600]}
```

Comment: I have no idea where some of these values are coming from, but your question is probably answered by one of: `zip()`, the fact that dictionaries guarantee iteration order is insertion order in python >=3.8 or `dict.items()`.

Comment: @c2huc2hu what values are you referring to? the datetime objects? If you run the `for loop`, the weeks dict will be populated. Can you elaborate on how you'd use `zip()`?

Comment: What is the `value` dictionary and where does it come from? It has the same structure as `weeks?

Comment: @IainShelvington `value` dictionary will have the same structure as `weeks`, yes. I have updated the code with what the dict looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate over two lists in parallel, it will yield pairs in tuples

```
[create(i, j) for i, j in zip(weeks[1], value[1]))
```